# display pfquery on table view controller

Tags: swift, parse-platform, attributes, uitableview

I ad developing an ios application with swift.  I am using parse as backend 
I have 2 classes 
class has(Name , Owner> pointer to _user class )
member( member_user> pointer to user who sign up to the class, ObjectId > pointer to class)

I wanted to get the classes that the member sign up with. I am able to retrieve  the exact classes but the problem is I am not  getting the name of the class displayed in the cell

```
 required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    self.parseClassName = "class"
    self.textKey = "Name"
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = true
    self.paginationEnabled = true
    self.objectsPerPage = 20
}



override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery! {

     var query1 = PFQuery(className: "class")
    //query1.whereKey("member_user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())

   var query2 = PFQuery(className: "MEMBER")
   query2.whereKey("member_user", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser())
    query2.whereKey("ObjectId", matchesKey: "objectId", inQuery: query1)
    return query2}



override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject) -> PFTableViewCell {


    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as PFTableViewCell!
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    if cell == nil {
        cell = PFTableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text =
        object["Name"] as String!
    return cell

}
```